# Set Theory - Well Order (Lexiographical combination)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning, order-theory, constructive-mathematics, type-theory

**Question:**

> Prove constructively that if $(A_{1},\prec_{1})$ and $(A_{2},\prec_{2})$ are two well-ordered sets then their lexicographical combination $(A_{1} \times A_{2},<_{1,2})$ is also well ordered.

I have tried to *spell out* all the things I think are necessary to prove the desired result constructively, namely:

If $(A_{1},\prec_{1})$ and $(A_{2},\prec_{2})$ are two sets with relations, then we can form the juxtaposition of these $(A_{1} \times A_{2}, \prec_{1,2})$
\begin{equation}
(a,b) \prec_{1,2} (c,d) \iff a \prec_{1} c \lor I(A_{1},a,c) \land b \prec_{2} d
\end{equation}
where we define
\begin{align}
&inl(a) \prec_{1,2} inl(b) \iff a \prec_{1} b
\\ &inl(a) \prec_{1,2} inr(b) \iff \top
\\ &inr(b) \prec_{1,2} inl(a) \iff \bot
\\ &inr(a) \prec_{1,2} inr(b) \iff a \prec_{2} b
\end{align}

Now, by definition, a **well-order** means that we have a well founded linear order; which is to say that for every progressive predicate $P$ on A, $(\forall x:A)P(x)$ **and** $x \prec_{1} y \lor x=_{1}y \lor y \prec_{1} x$.

However, I struggle to connect find a brief, sound and constructive argument that will answer the question. That is why I humble I ask this forum for help, hoping someone more enlighten may guide me to greater understanding. Thanks!

Comment: It seems as if, when $P(a,b)$ is a progressive relation on $A_1 \times A_2$, the relation $Q(a)$ on $A_1$ defined as $Q(a) = (\forall b \in A_2)P(a, b)$ will be progressive on $A_1$...

Comment: @CarlMummert I thought I had to prove $a \prec_{1,2} b$ on $A_{1},A_{2}$ was progressive rather than on $A_{1}$?

Comment: Don't you need to prove that given a progressive relation on $A_1\times A_2$, it covers all of that order? And you know that, if you have a progressive relation on $A_1$, it must cover all of $A_1$.

Comment: @CarlMummert How about this? To show that $A_{1} \times A_{2}, <_{1,2}$ (I use > for 2 below) is well ordered: Take two elements: $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2) \in A_{1} \times A_{2}$.
Then there are three cases:
1. $a_1 < a_2$. in this case $(a_1,b_1) < (a_2,b_2)$
2. $a_1 > a_2$. in this case $(a_1,b_1) > (a_2,b_2)$ 
3. $a_1 = a_2$. in this case: if $ b_1 > b_2$ then $(a_1,b_1) > (a_2,b_2)$.
if $b_1 < b_2$ then $(a_1,b_1) < (a_2,b_2)$. and if $b_1 = b_2$ then $(a_1,b_1) = (a_2,b_2)$.

Comment: Secondly, I need to show that $A_{1} \times A_{2}$ has a minimum element. Take $P \subseteq A_{1} \times A_{2}$, a non empty set. $P := \{ (a_i,b_j)| a_i \in A_{1}, b_j \in A_{2} \}$. Where $i,j \in I$ and $I$ is a linearly ordered set of indexes. Then the set $\{a_i | (a_i,b_j) \in A_{1} \times A_{2}\}$ has a minimal element: $a_{i_0}$. Also the set $\{ b_j | (a_{i_0},b_j) \}$ has a minimal element $b_{j_0}$. So the element $(a_{i_0},b_{i_0})$ is a minimal element of $U$